# Getting not a valid GraphQL query in hasura

Tags: javascript, database, graphql, graphql-js, hasura

With the use of Authorization, the error occurs but not when x-hasura-admin-secret is used. I am trying to insert an individual user.

Output:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "extensions": {
        "path": "$.selectionSet.insert_users.args.objects",
        "code": "permission-error"
      },
      "message": "check constraint of an insert/update permission has failed"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my query.

```
mutation MyMutation {
  insert_users(objects: {email: "ss", first_name: "dcy", last_name: "bc", public_address: "dfutdiytdg", user_id: "hcjh"}, on_conflict: {constraint: users_email_key}) {
    affected_rows
    returning {
      id
      first_name
      email
    }
  }
}
```

In my users permission, both update and insert have all toggled on.

Comment: No special [row insert permissions](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/databases/postgres/schema/data-validations/#using-hasura-permissions)?

Comment: You might be failing some constraint checks of insertion/updation